# Platform ios already installed

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I'm tryin' to debug my app on iOS simulator in my Mac.

I've followed all the instructions installing on my Mac:

```
sudo npm install -g vs-mda-remote

sudo npm install -g ios-sim
```

When I prompted

```
vs-mda-remote --buildDir Projects
```

(Projects is the folder where debug files will be droped), I see results in my PC by

```
http://<MAc_IP>:3000
```

With the following text

> Remote build Express server open for business on port 3000

Ok, now I prompted

```
vs-mda-remote test
```

And I see an error with the following message

> Failed to build app: CordovaError: Platform ios already added

I don't know what happen.

Comment: .@Shanty - Any chance you could pipe output to a file and share it? Use the command:
 
vs-mda-remote –buildDir Projects > builds.log 2>&1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. Maybe, I'm too eagier.

Instead of using one session in terminal app on mac, I used too many, so, when I prompted too many times`vs-mda-remote`, obviously ios was already installed.

So, opening terminal at first time, and prompting

```
vs-mda-remote --buildDir Projects --allowsEmulate=true
```

Now, I can debug on iOS simulator from my PC to Mac.

Comment: Didnt need to run this command in my case. Just closed all the terminal windows but one. Tried again and success! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While running the build agent, the correct command is:

```
vs-mda-remote --buildDir <server-build-directory> --allowsEmulate=true
```

Note the last "--allowsEmulate=true" part of the command.

*Taken from "Setting up the Remote Agent to Support Starting the iOS Simulator" section in the [documentation](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397716).

Answer (score 0):

Platform ios already installed

Received this error for running in device too, while running multiple instance in mac.
Quit Terminal and run single instance for vs-mda-remote to resolve this problem if you receive this error for running in Device.